# Firefox Add-ons want to change add-ons button as per webpage element's attribute data-status change into Panel

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Through Firefox latest SDK addon-sdk-1.17 I try to develop Add-ons.
I have a webpage into FF Add-on's **Panel** and I want to change add-ons colour or image or some things to indicate change/update into webpage of panel.
More Specific situation is, in a web page there is anchor element with id `<a title="" data-original-title="" data-status="" id="message-icon"...` this will be change as `<a title="" data-original-title="" data-status="has-messages" id="message-icon"...` Please note that `data-status="has-messages"`change. I want to grab this change and send message to user through Firefox add-ons.

I know there is method of "content scripts" of `port.emit()` and `port.on()`. The content script sends messages using self.port.emit() and the add-on script receives them using panel.port.on() but through tutorials and SDK documents I didn't get idea how to do this in my situation. Please help.

Thanks in advance.